# C++ optimization of boolean or operator

Tags: c++, if-statement, optimization, boolean

I have the following code which works as expected:

```
bool result=false;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(face[i].intersect(*coordinates, org, dir))
    {
        result = true;
    }
}
return result;
```

But this one has a different behavior (the value pointed to by `coordinates` is different)

```
bool result=false;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    result = result || faceList[i].intersect(*coordinates, org, dir, triangle);
}
return result;
```

What's the reason for this? Is the expression after `||` never evaluated if the one before is true? I thought this optimization was allowed only in an `if` statement.

Comment: Has nothing to do with an `if` statement, it has to do with the `||` operator itself. You *don't* get this behavior only if you make your own `operator||`. P.S. It evaluates left to right, so put the thing you always want evaluated on the left.

Comment: You compare apples with bananas (The reason to close it is wrong - but closing it is good).